# Internet Explorer doesn't cache my videos

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a typical gamer clan page (ilch CMS) and I took videos to set them as a video background.

I use this code to embed them :

```
$erg = db_query('SELECT * FROM `prefix_videobg` Where active = 1');

while ($r = db_fetch_assoc($erg)) {
   $string = $r['file'];
   $position_des_letzten_punktes = strrpos($string, '.');
   $dname = substr($string, 0, $position_des_letzten_punktes);
   echo '<video class="covervid-video" autoplay loop poster="video-fallback.png">';
   echo ' <source src="./upload/'.$dname.'.webm" type="video/webm">';
   echo ' <source src="./upload/'.$dname.'.mp4" type="video/mp4">';
   echo '</video>';
   echo '<script src="include/designs/TiWlog/covervid.min.js"></script>';
   echo '<!-- Call CoverVid -->';
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(".covervid-video").coverVid(1920, 1080);</script>';
}
```

As you can see, I have a database with all videos and I can choose via the admin panel which one is active.

It runs perfectly and I did a browser test and all browsers display the video properly.

But then I realized that only IE is downloading the video each time resulting lots of waste traffic for IE users.

I checked the page in Chrome: the video loads once and is then cached until a new video is activated.
Opera: same as Chrome.
Firefox: same as Chrome.
IE: Downloads the video on each page load.

I tried the manifest option, but IE is still downloading the video file from the server instead of fetching it from cache.

Any idea why this happens?

## **[UPDATE]**

IE compatiblity view dosent help.

Want to test it yourself? check the page @ [tiw](http://www.this-is-war.com)

Answer (score 0):

add your page to Internet Explorer's Compatibility View Settings. You won't believe how many issues Compatibility View fixes.

Comment: thx for the answer - this didn´t help .. with compatiblity on - my CMS stop to work and the videos aren´t shown.